# How can I remove the zeros from an integer?

Tags: java, syntax

How can I remove all the zero's from an integer?
If the int is only a zero, it will return 0 but if it isn't , it returns an integer that is the same except it doesn't have any 0's.

I tried to pass it to a String and then to an integer after the removal was done, but it comes with the 0's again.

How can I do it?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // test method removeZeros
        test_removeZeros(0); // result = 0
        test_removeZeros(2); // result = 2
        test_removeZeros(10); // result = 1
        test_removeZeros(101); // result = 11
        test_removeZeros(10050); // result = 15
        test_removeZeros(-30100); // result = -31
        System.out.println();

    }

    private static void test_removeZeros(int n) {

        try {

            System.out.print("removeZeros (" + n + ") = ");
            int res = removeZeros(n);
            System.out.println(res);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static int removeZeros(int n) {
            int finalresult= n;
            int result;
            String medium;


            if (n == 0){

                result= 0;
                result= finalresult;

            } else{

                medium= Integer.toString(n);        
                int x = Integer.parseInt(medium.substring(0));
                result= Integer.valueOf(medium);
                result= finalresult;

            }

            finalresult = result;
            return finalresult;

        }
```

Comment: do you need to remove the zeros at the end of the integer or all the zeros even in the middle ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, it is unclear what `passagem` is.

Comment: @Turing85 Yeah, my bad. It was meant to be "medium".

Comment: Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(a).replace("0", ""))

Comment: @Yahya Every 0, either it is in the middle or the end or the beggining.

Comment: @DarkKool this does not make the given code a MVCE. Please provide full executable code (including a `main` method) with input that produces unexpected output.

Comment: @Turing85 I think that's what you want

Comment: You aren't removing zeros from integers, you're removing the representation of zeros from strings.

Comment: @Lew Bloch yeah, I know. But I don't know other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do something like this:

```
int intWithZeros = 1020300; // for example
String intAsString = String.valueOf(intWithZeros); // represent the int as a String
String resultString= "";
for (char digit : intAsString.toCharArray()) { // cycle through every char 
    if(digit!='0') { // if it is not a zero
     resultString+=digit; // append it to the resultString
    }
}
if (!resultString.equals("")) {
    return Integer.parseInt(resultString);
}
return 0;
```

**Input:**

```
1020300
```

**Output:**

```
123
```

Comment: You should provide explanation by default, not on request. This also helps future readers to understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(a).replace("0", ""))
```

The above single line checks converts Int to String Removes All character with 0. And then convert back to int. In above answer a represents the int variable.
And you may need to check the `if a != 0` before you do this operation since it throws NumberFormatException

```
 private static int removeZeros(int a) {

     if (a != 0) {

         return Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(a).replace("0", ""))
     }
     return 0
 }
```

Comment: While this may fix the problem, code-only answers are discouraged. Please explain your answer.

Comment: @Turing85 may be you can mark it answered, If It had answered the question.

Comment: @ShankarShastri What is "a" suppose to be replaced with?

Comment: @Turing85 my bad did'nt see that :(

Comment: @Shankar Shastri what is n?¬

Comment: @Yahya thanks for catching that, copy paste problem :P

Answer (score 1):

It dismays me to see this only answered using string conversion. It's just not necessary, and more interesting if you don't use it.

Instead, you can solve it recursively: go through each of the digits in turn, adding them to the result if they are non-zero. Something like this:

```
int withoutZeros(int i) {
  return withoutZeros(i, 0, 1);
}

int withoutZeros(int remainingDigits, int result, int mul) {
  // mul is the multiplier to put the last digit in the right place
  // in the result. For instance, if mul is 100, and the last digit
  // of remainingDigits is 4, the final result will end with 4??.

  // There are no more digits; so return the result.
  if (remainingDigits == 0) return result;

  int lastDigit = remainingDigits % 10;

  // The last digit is a zero, so we don't include in the result.
  if (lastDigit == 0) return withoutZeros(i / 10, result, mul);

  // Otherwise, add the last digit of i to the result.
  // We have to multiply by mul in order to put this digit
  // "in the right place" in the result (because this processes
  // the digits in reverse order).
  // Increase mul for the next iteration.
  return withoutZeros(i / 10, result + lastDigit * mul, 10 * mul);
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/WWUjHl)

and since this is tail-recursive, you can write it as a loop:

```
int withoutZeros(int i) {
  int result = 0;
  for (int remainingDigits = i, mul = 1; remainingDigits > 0; remainingDigits /= 10) {
    int lastDigit = remainingDigits % 10;
    if (lastDigit != 0) {
      result += lastDigit * mul;
      mul *= 10;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: But the intention is not to sum but to put int without the zero's

Comment: Yep. See the demo link, this produces the desired output from the question.